# applying a definition on 3 selected parts in single column in a dataframe and 8 fixed values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, definition

I am trying to interpolate values with constant coordinate values and changing wind speed values which I have in one text-file. With using this definition:

```
def bary_interpol (inter_cor_x1, inter_cor_x2, inter_cor_x3, inter_cor_y1,
                   inter_cor_y2, inter_cor_y3, inter_cor_px, inteR_cor_py,
                   inter_wind_v1, inter_wind_v2, inter_wind_v3):
    W_v1 = ((inter_cor_y2-inter_cor_y3)*(inter_cor_px-inter_cor_x3)+
            (inter_cor_x3-inter_cor_x2)*(inter_cor_py-inter_cor_y3))/((inter_cor_y2-inter_cor_y3)*(inter_cor_x1-inter_cor_x3)+
            (inter_cor_x3-inter_cor_x2)*(inter_cor_y1-inter_cor_y3))
    W_v2 = ((inter_cor_y3-inter_cor_y1)*(inter_cor_px-inter_cor_x3)+
            (inter_cor_x1-inter_cor_x3)*(inter_cor_py-inter_cor_y3))/((inter_cor_y2-inter_cor_y3)*(inter_cor_x1-inter_cor_x3)+
            (inter_cor_x3-inter_cor_x2)*(inter_cor_y1-inter_cor_y3))
    W_v3 = 1 - W_v1 - W_v2
    inter_wind_pv = (W_v1 * inter_wind_v1) + (W_v2 * inter_wind_v2) +  (W_v3 * inter_wind_v3)
    return inter_wind_pv
```

This definition works for me now but only when all variables are constant. But the inter_wind_v1, inter_wind_v2 and inter_wind_v3 need to be added from the text-file.

The values in column (FF) I have already found by the identification number which is in the same row as the FF. STN_V1 actually stands for 235. I used this method:

```
inter_wind_v1 = wind[wind['STN'] == STN_v1]
print(inter_wind_v1)

inter_wind_v2 = wind[wind['STN'] == STN_v2]
print(inter_wind_v2)

inter_wind_v3 = wind[wind['STN'] == STN_v3]
print(inter_wind_v3)
```

This will print the selected data I needed.

```
          STN        DT     FF
10464  235  20210101     20
10465  235  20210101     30
10466  235  20210101     20
10467  235  20210101     20
10468  235  20210101     20
   ...       ...    ...
20923  235  20220312     40
20924  235  20220312     50
20925  235  20220312     50
20926  235  20220312     50
20927  235  20220312     60

[10464 rows x 3 columns]
       STN        DT     FF
20928  242  20210101     80
20929  242  20210101     60
................................ etc.
```

But I can not figure out how to make a new list or data frame with the definition I made to interpolate.

So I am trying to make a interpolated new column FF of combining the three FF's column referenced as inter_wind_v in the definition.

I hope anybody can help me with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this may be a way to do what your question asks:

```py
import pandas as pd
def bary_interpol (inter_cor_x1, inter_cor_x2, inter_cor_x3, inter_cor_y1,
                   inter_cor_y2, inter_cor_y3, inter_cor_px, inter_cor_py,
                   inter_wind_v1, inter_wind_v2, inter_wind_v3):
    W_v1 = ((inter_cor_y2-inter_cor_y3)*(inter_cor_px-inter_cor_x3)+
            (inter_cor_x3-inter_cor_x2)*(inter_cor_py-inter_cor_y3))/((inter_cor_y2-inter_cor_y3)*(inter_cor_x1-inter_cor_x3)+
            (inter_cor_x3-inter_cor_x2)*(inter_cor_y1-inter_cor_y3))
    W_v2 = ((inter_cor_y3-inter_cor_y1)*(inter_cor_px-inter_cor_x3)+
            (inter_cor_x1-inter_cor_x3)*(inter_cor_py-inter_cor_y3))/((inter_cor_y2-inter_cor_y3)*(inter_cor_x1-inter_cor_x3)+
            (inter_cor_x3-inter_cor_x2)*(inter_cor_y1-inter_cor_y3))
    W_v3 = 1 - W_v1 - W_v2
    inter_wind_pv = (W_v1 * inter_wind_v1) + (W_v2 * inter_wind_v2) +  (W_v3 * inter_wind_v3)
    return inter_wind_pv

wind_records = [
    {'STN':235, 'DT':20210101, 'FF':20},
    {'STN':235, 'DT':20210101, 'FF':30},
    {'STN':235, 'DT':20210101, 'FF':20},
    {'STN':236, 'DT':20210101, 'FF':20},
    {'STN':236, 'DT':20210101, 'FF':20},
    {'STN':236, 'DT':20210101, 'FF':40},
    {'STN':237, 'DT':20210101, 'FF':50},
    {'STN':237, 'DT':20210101, 'FF':50},
    {'STN':237, 'DT':20210101, 'FF':50}
]
wind = pd.DataFrame(wind_records)

STN_v1 = 235
inter_wind_v1 = wind[wind['STN'] == STN_v1].reset_index()
print(f"inter_wind_v1:\n{inter_wind_v1}")

STN_v2 = 236
inter_wind_v2 = wind[wind['STN'] == STN_v2].reset_index()
print(f"inter_wind_v2:\n{inter_wind_v2}")

STN_v3 = 237
inter_wind_v3 = wind[wind['STN'] == STN_v3].reset_index()
print(f"inter_wind_v3:\n{inter_wind_v3}")

interp = pd.DataFrame(inter_wind_v1['FF']).rename(columns = {'FF':'inter_wind_v1'})
interp['inter_wind_v2'] = inter_wind_v2['FF']
interp['inter_wind_v3'] = inter_wind_v3['FF']
print(interp)

inter_cor_x1, inter_cor_x2, inter_cor_x3 = 0.1, 0.01, -0.1
inter_cor_y1, inter_cor_y2, inter_cor_y3 = 0.2, 0.05, -0.1
inter_cor_px, inter_cor_py = 0.22, -0.22
def doInterp(inter_wind_v1, inter_wind_v2, inter_wind_v3):
    return bary_interpol (inter_cor_x1, inter_cor_x2, inter_cor_x3, inter_cor_y1,
                   inter_cor_y2, inter_cor_y3, inter_cor_px, inter_cor_py,
                   inter_wind_v1, inter_wind_v2, inter_wind_v3)
interp['inter_wind_pv'] = interp.apply(lambda x: doInterp(x['inter_wind_v1'], x['inter_wind_v2'], x['inter_wind_v3']), axis=1)
print(interp)
```

Output:

```
inter_wind_v1:
   index  STN        DT  FF
0      0  235  20210101  20
1      1  235  20210101  30
2      2  235  20210101  20
inter_wind_v2:
   index  STN        DT  FF
0      3  236  20210101  20
1      4  236  20210101  20
2      5  236  20210101  40
inter_wind_v3:
   index  STN        DT  FF
0      6  237  20210101  50
1      7  237  20210101  50
2      8  237  20210101  50
   inter_wind_v1  inter_wind_v2  inter_wind_v3
0             20             20             50
1             30             20             50
2             20             40             50
   inter_wind_v1  inter_wind_v2  inter_wind_v3  inter_wind_pv
0             20             20             50         -538.0
1             30             20             50         -742.0
2             20             40             50          262.0
```

I have made the following assumptions:

- used sample values for `STN_v1`, `STN_v2` and `STN_v3` and the dataframe content
- assumed that the number of items is the same for `inter_wind_v1`, `inter_wind_v2` and `inter_wind_v3`
- assumed that the other arguments of the `bary_interpol()` function are scalars (constant), and that you want to call the function repeatedly using the same argument values except for `inter_wind_v1`, `inter_wind_v2` and `inter_wind_v3`

Comment: @SimonDL Did this work for you?